# what is the best way to backup my android apps data

Tags: java, android, android-backup-service

I would like my app to backup the user data that they create on my app to google drive account of user.

I have looked at few ways to do it, but I would like to know what is the best way?

I did use `android:fullBackupContent="true"` but I don't see any data saved on google drive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's being backed up but you can't manually view it. It simply uses GDrive as backend but that's about it

Comment: Check out Firebase Authentification.Firebase is not complicated to use or learn. If you are using it for small app and for studying it is ok. If you exceed a certain number of request, Google will make you pay some fees.